# Is there a way to add lines to a rc file based on the current shell used

Tags: bash, shell

Is this easily possible in a bash script?
I am trying to make a dotfile installer for my personal dotfiles and I cant figure out how to add them based on the shell.

This is the current code I have:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

shell=0

if [$(echo $0) = '/bin/bash';
  then
    set -o shell 1
    echo -e 'if [ -f /home/$USER/.bash_aliases ]; then\n  source /home/$USER/.bash_aliases\nfi\n' > /home/$USER/.bashrc
elif [$(echo $0) = '/bin/zsh';
  then
    set -o shell 2
    echo -e 'if [ -f /home/$USER/.bash_aliases ]; then\n  source /home/$USER/.bash_aliases\nfi\n' > /home/$USER/.zshrc
fi

if [shell=1];then
  cat /home/$USER/.bashrc | grep ".bash_aliases" >/dev/null && echo "susess!" || && echo "this script has failed"
elif [shell=2];then
  cat /home/$USER/.zshrc | grep ".bash_aliases" >/dev/null && echo "susess!" || && echo "this script has failed"
fi
```

Comment: I would just append the line to `.zshrc/.bashrc` based on the existence of said files, eg: `[[ -f /home/$USER/.zshrc ]] && echo -e '.... line to append to' >> /home/$USER/.zshrc`, then do the same thing for `/home/$USER/.bashrc`  (I'm assuming you don't want `> /home/$USER/.zshrc`  as this will overwrite the entire file with the single line you're printing)

Comment: Just add them all, so that they're available whenever you need to run the appropriate shell. It's not like they are going to put a dent in your available disk space.

Comment: You shouldn't be reusing the same alias file for `bash` and `zsh` anyway.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.